# How to deal with unnecessary "Please post a jsFiddle" comments

Tags: discussion, comments, jsfiddle

A definite stance on the use of jsfiddle as a resource for displaying code relevant to a question hasn't really been reached. We've had quite a few questions regarding this on meta but I don't think they've done much justice to the community's overall standpoint on the situation.

That being said, I'm personally all for jsfiddle, but **not for using it as the only source** for displaying your code. In fact, askers **should** utilize jsfiddle, especially if their entire code (or at least what they feels is relevant to the problem) is rather large. **However, they should still *always* have some code in the question,** whether it be a small part of the whole code that they feel may summarize the problem as best as possible, or the entire code itself in the case that it's not that huge.

When askers don't make use of (or simply aren't aware of) jsfiddle, we usually post a comment suggesting that they post a live example there for us to  *really* get to know what the problem is (seeing the product of the 'broken' code is very helpful in identifying the problem). Sometimes I come across questions whose answers can be determined by simply looking more closely at the code, as oftentimes the simple mistakes are our downfall.

So my question is mainly how to deal with comments that suggest putting the code into a jsfiddle in cases like above, where it's not really necessary. After all, it is something of an added inconvenience to have to go to a separate site to work with the user's code.

For a quick example of what I'm talking about (although probably not a perfect one), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673377/what-is-this-code-doing-im-unsure-of-this-role-and-new-to-the-jquery/#comment-10781157) recent comment, I feel, suggests posting the code on jsfiddle when it's not really necessary.

Comment: If it's not really necessary, then the best thing to do is ignore the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is mainly how to deal with comments that suggest putting the code into a jsfiddle in cases like above, where it's not really necessary. After all, it is something of an added inconvenience to have to go to a separate site to work with the user's code.

If it seems to be mindless auto-posted noise that doesn't help anybody at all, just flag it as not constructive. Three flags on a comment within a day or two will remove it automatically if a mod doesn't get to it right away.

If you don't feel comfortable flagging, or aren't sure if it's totally unnecessary, you can discuss it with them in the comments, or even drag them to a chat room if it gets long, but you don't have to.

For what it's worth, I try to only ask people to set up fiddles if it seems realistic to construct such isolated test cases.